# LWJGL Display.isCloseRequested() throwing an error?

Tags: java, macos, lwjgl

Well I am currently using a Mac, and I was just creating a simple LWJGL test program to make sure the library would work... but when I try to get the closed requested state for the Display, it throws an error...

I am currently using Mac OSX 10.7.5, I am using LWJGL 2.8.5, and I'm running the latest java (1.7.0_13). If this is an error made by me, please don't hesitate to point it out.

The error:

```
JavaVM WARNING: JAWT_GetAWT must be called after loading a JVM
Fatal error: Unable to create window.
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not get the JAWT interface
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine close requested state of uncreated window
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.isCloseRequested(Display.java:546)
    at lwjgltest.LWJGLTest.start(LWJGLTest.java:26)
    at lwjgltest.LWJGLTest.main(LWJGLTest.java:13)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

The code:

```
package lwjgltest;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

/**
 *
 * @author DealerNextDoor
 */
public class LWJGLTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LWJGLTest().start(); // Line 13
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
            Display.setTitle("LWJGL Test");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            System.err.println("Fatal error: Unable to create window.");
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) { // Line 26

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'll look at your error you will find that a window was not created: `Fatal error: Unable to create window.`

As a result, you cannot use the method `isCloseRequested()`.

I think that you will find some information about why it is not creating [here](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php?topic=4326.30)

Comment: Well if I can't use `isCloseRequested()`, then what should I use to see if the user is trying to close the window?

Comment: @DealerNextDoor The problem in the first place is that the window is **NOT** created. You can see it in the first few lines of your error.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized I forgot to add `System.exit(1)` to the end of the catch statement, so I was associating the `Exception in thread "main" ...`, my bad. That was just a very, very stupid mistake on my part...

Comment: @DealerNextDoor But, unfortunately this won't help you. It will just make your application exit before it reaches the `isCloseRequested()` check. If you'll look at the link I've provided in the answer you will find that there maybe a problem with this library on OSX 10 and Java 7 (and maybe even 6).

Comment: Yeah, I saw. Apparently, LWJGL is completely broken under Java 7 OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading java to 1.6 should help.

Comment: I think I'll just wait until I'm back on my computer, but thanks anyway. This probably would fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my `Display.create();` to the class constructor instead of inside a method and the "Cannot determine close requested state of uncreated window" error went away.

```
public Core() { // Main class constructor

    try {
        LibraryLoader.loadNativeLibraries();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Error Loading Natives!");
    }

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Display.create();
        input = new InputHandler();
        Display.setTitle(TITLE);
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
        cleanUp();

    }
    initGL();
    mainLoop();

}
```